# Unit testing .timeout() operator constantly returns TimeoutException

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Spend a few hours trying to figure out why my unit test keeps returning a TimeoutException on an Rx chain that has a timeout operator. Without any luck, I dumbed down my chain to just the timeout operator, and it still fails.

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Custom timeout")
    fun customTimeout() {
        val observer: TestObserver<Boolean> = TestObserver()
        val scheduler = TestScheduler()
        val subject: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create()

        subject.subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe(observer)

        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        subject.onNext(true)
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        subject.onNext(false)
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        observer.await().assertValueCount(2)
    }
```

Can someone please tell me why the values are not coming through?

Comment: Use `scheduler` as the 3rd parameter to `timeout()`.

Comment: Sweet! That works. But what if the timeout operator is outside of the test code? How would I pass the scheduler in that case?

Comment: Search SO for TestScheduler `@Rule` definitions for example.